# Why does (list 'quote 1) evaluates to '1 instead of 1?

Tags: lisp

I need some enlightenment with the combined use of `list` and `quote`.

Here is what I see:

```
[1]> (list '1)
(1)
```

Fair enough. `(list '1)` becomes `"('1)"` which evaluates to `(1)` since `'` just returns what goes after it.

```
[2]> (list 'quote 1)
'1
```

Why not `1`, why the `'` went unevaluated here because:

```
[3]> '1
1
```

As a general question, am I wrong that the evaluation process will try to resolve everything it can find recursively?

Answer (score 3):

Since `list` is supposed to construct a list of its arguments, it would be quite strange if it were to return a number. Indeed, `'1` is a two element list, containing as its elements the symbol `quote` and the number 1:

```
CL-USER> (first (list 'quote 1))
QUOTE
CL-USER> (second (list 'quote 1))
1
```

The reason it appears as `'1` rather than `(QUOTE 1)` is because your Lisp system prints single-element lists that begin with `quote` specially.

> `(list '1)` becomes `"('1)"` which evaluates to `(1)`

This is not correct. As `list` is an ordinary function, its argument forms are evaluated to give the value of each argument. In this case the form `'1` will be evaluated to the value `1`, which `list` will receive as its single argument. There is no evaluation of the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Note, I'm assuming Common Lisp here.

**First a few definItions/notes**:

- something like `(list 1)` is called a *form*. A *form* is a Lisp object meant to be evaluated.
- Since it is a list, it is called a *compound form*.
- Since the first element of the *compound form* is `list` and it stands for a function, it is called a *function form*.
- The first element of a *function form* is the function and the rest elements are the *arguments*.

**Printing a quote form**

`'foo` is the same as `(quote foo)`, since the *quote* character is a *reader macro*, which converts the form `'foo` at read time into `(quote foo)`

But how is it printed? The can depend on the value of the variable `*print-pretty*`. If this variable has the value `T`, then the *printer* uses the *pretty printer*.

```
* *print-pretty*

T
* '(quote 1)

'1
```

But when we don't use the pretty printer to print result values:

```
* (setf *print-pretty* nil)

NIL
* '(quote 1)

(QUOTE 1)
```

Thus Lisp can print the same thing in different ways, depending on its configuration.

**Evaluation of function forms**

When function forms are evaluated, we already know that the first element is a function and the rest elements are the arguments.

Thus in `(list '1)` we see:

- `list` is the function
- `'1` is the only argument

Now each of the arguments are evaluated to values:

- `'1` is evaluated to `1`, since the `quote` *operator* just returns the enclosed object. So the result value is `1`.

Since all arguments are evaluated we can call `list` with the argument value `1`.

This then returns `(1)`, since `list` returns a list of all the provided argument values.

**The second example**

Now let's look at the second example: `(list 'quote 1)`.

We have again a function form with the function `list`. But now we have two arguments `'quote` and `1`.

We need to evaluate each argument from left to right.

`'quote` evaluates to the symbol `quote`.

`1` evaluates to `1`, since numbers are self-evaluating like most objects (exceptions are symbols and lists).

So we call the function `list` with the argument values `quote` and `1`.

List makes a list of its argument values. Thus the result is `(quote 1)`.

Now remember: `(quote 1)` is the same as `'1)`. Thus the printer may print the latter variant.

So we have a list as a result, which can either be printed as `(quote 1)` or `'1`. But that makes otherwise no difference:

```
CL-USER 7 > (equal (quote (quote 1)) ''1)
T
```

**Evaluation is done once**

> As a general question, am I wrong that the evaluation process will try to resolve everything it can find recursively?

The result of a *form* is not again evaluated. Evaluation of is done only once: the form itself is evaluated.